# Delphi: two fields at same memory location - compiler bug?

Tags: delphi, generics

I tried this in Delphi XE SP 1, see comment in code.
Never tried in newer revisions, have not installed them now, is somebody familiar with this bug? Didn't find anything in their QC either...

```
unit Testing;

interface

uses
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TBaseObjectList<T: class> = class(TObjectList<T>)
  private
    FUpdateLock: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    procedure LockUpdate;
    procedure UnlockUpdate;
    function UpdateUnlocked: Boolean;
    property UpdateLock: Integer read FUpdateLock;
  end;

  TAdvObject = class(TObject)
  end;

  TAdvObjectList = class(TBaseObjectList<TAdvObject>)
  private
    FHelper: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
    property Helper: Integer read Fhelper;
  end;

implementation

{ TBaseObjectList<T> }

constructor TBaseObjectList<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FUpdateLock := 0;
end;

procedure TBaseObjectList<T>.LockUpdate;
begin
  Inc(FUpdateLock);
end;

procedure TBaseObjectList<T>.UnlockUpdate;
begin
  if FUpdateLock > 0 then
    Dec(FUpdateLock);
end;

function TBaseObjectList<T>.UpdateUnlocked: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FUpdateLock = 0;
end;

{ TAdvObjectList }

constructor TAdvObjectList.Create;
begin
  LockUpdate;
  try
    // this increments FUpdateLock as well because FHelper and FUpdateLock are mapped to same memory location, it can be seen in debugger watches, it seems to me to be a bug
    Inc(FHelper);
  finally
    UnlockUpdate;
  end;
end;

begin
  TAdvObjectList.Create;
end.
```

Thank you TK

Comment: Can you include code that outputs the fields in question. Perhaps it's just a debugger fault.

Comment: Have you checked the value in program (`Assert(FUpdateLock = 1)`) ?

Comment: I can confirm this, Debugger watch shows the same values for both fields and TLama's assertion fails..

Comment: Trying the same code in XE7 does not expose the issue, so I suspect we have a bug.

Comment: I can't find nothing related in QC. The workaround is very simple, define `TAdvObjectList` in its own unit.

Comment: There is is: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=101308

Comment: Yes that seems to be the correct one.

Comment: @StefanGlienke - You should post that as an answer.  Known bug, QC link, resolved in XE4.

Comment: @StefanGlienke exactly this is the bug report I was looking for thank you. I have to learn how to search in QC. For those who still cannot upgrade to later Delphi versions (as is my case) this bug only affects the first field declared in TAdvObjectList. So the workaroung is adding e.g. a FDummy: Integer as first field to derived class.

Comment: @tk_ a better workaround is to put the derived class in its own unit, no dummy field needed.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I didn't notice your previous post - I had this and the bug was still there (I use ver. 15.0.3953.35171). The above example was only an excerpt. Had to insert those dummies for every "TAdvObjectList" in my project. Soon we will need Delphi upgrade anyway so it is only a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying answer from the comments above:
qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=101308
Bug resolved in Delphi XE4.